# Can OpenAPI schema names have "/" in them?

Tags: openapi

I am consuming an API that uses string like "foo/bar" to identify (discriminate) JSON objects.

A `$ref` like `$ref: '#/components/schemas/foo/bar'` gives me errors.

Is this naming supported? I want to use leverage these properties provided by the API in order to use discrimination to pick the most appropriate component schema.

I am using OpenAPI 3.0.1.

Comment: Is "foo/bar" used as key _name_ or key _value_ in your JSON?

Comment: It’s the value, which I want to map to a swagger component schema

Comment: Then there's no reason to use `/` in schema _names_. You can name the schema `FooBar` and handle the mappings using [`discriminator.mappings`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#discriminator-object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

OpenAPI 3.0 component names (including schema names) can only contain these characters:

```
a-z A-Z 0-9 - . _
```

([Source](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#components-object))

However, there are no restrictions on *property names* in schemas, so `/` can be used in property names:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    MySchema:
      type: object
      properties:
        foo/bar:   # <-----
          type: string
```